# OpenGL glTexImage3D not working?

Tags: opengl, textures, lwjgl

I'm trying to use arrax textures with opengl 3.3 since this the target version for my application. So I have to use the `glTexImage3D()` method instead of `glTexStorage3D()`. The problem is, if I use `glTexImage3D()` instead of `glTexStorage3D()` the screen is always black. The other way round, everything works. Here is how I create the array texture:

```
public ArrayTexture(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.arrayTextureHandle = GL11.glGenTextures();
    GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, arrayTextureHandle);

        //Works perfect
        GL42.glTexStorage3D(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL11.GL_RGBA8, width, height, 10);
        //Doesn't work with these parameters
        //GL12.glTexImage3D(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA8, width, height, 10, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (ByteBuffer)null);

    GL11.glBindTexture(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0);
}

public void addTexture(ScrollingSprite... sprites) {
    if(zLayerCounter + sprites.length <= MAX_LAYERS) {
        GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, arrayTextureHandle);

        Arrays.asList(sprites).forEach(sprite -> {
            sprite.getTexture().getTextureData().prepare();
            GL12.glTexSubImage3D(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
                0,                      //Mipmap number
                0, 0, zLayerCounter++, //xoffset, yoffset, zoffset
                width, height, 1,          //width, height, depth
                GL11.GL_RGBA,                 //format
                GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,       //type
                sprite.getTexture().getTextureData().consumePixmap().getPixels()); //pointer to data

            GL11.glTexParameteri(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, sprite.getTextureWrapS());
            GL11.glTexParameteri(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, sprite.getTextureWrapT());
        });

        GL11.glBindTexture(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Maximum number of textures reached!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using glGetError

Comment: I get an error 1280, which means GL_INVALID_ENUM. But that error appears with both methods.

Comment: In the version that works you're only creating 10 aray slices.  In the version that doesn't work you're creating 100.  Have you checked your hardware maximums?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at http://docs.gl/gl3/glTexImage3D, the 8th parameter (*`format`*) has to be one of `GL_RED, GL_RG, GL_RGB, GL_BGR, GL_RGBA, and GL_BGRA`, you use `GL_RGBA8` which is not allowed. Use `GL_RGBA` instead.

Comment: Still not working. I tried all different parameters listed in the docs.

Comment: Do you still get an `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error? Check for errors after __each__ gl*-Call to find out which one throws the error.

Comment: no that error has nothing to do with the array texture. I get no error at all calling `glTexImage3D()` or `glTexStorage3D()`.